# How to solve Ax=b for large condition numbers

Tags: scipy, solver, eigen3

I am dealing with highly ill-conditioned matrix (cond> 10^25).
I have tried most of scipy methods: `splu`, `gmers` `solve`
and `pyamg.krylov.steepest_descent` from PyAMG.

also iterative Refinement method:

```py
def iterRef(A, b, tol=1e-5, maxiter=100, verbose=True):
    """
    Solve the equation a x = b for x using Iterative Refinement method.

    :param A: [(M,M) array_like] A square matrix.
    :param b: [(M,) array like]Right-hand side matrix in a x = b.
    :param maxIter: [int] max number of iteration for convergence.
    :param t:  #!
    :return x: (M,) or (M, N) ndarray
        Solution to the system a x = b. Shape of the return matches the shape of b.

    **Reference:**
        Burden, R.L. and Faires, J.D., 2011. Numerical analysis.
    """

    
    # declarations
    n = len(b)
    xx = np.zeros_like(b)
    r = np.zeros_like(b)

    lu = splu(A)
    x = lu.solve(b)
    res = np.sum(A.dot(x)-b)
    print("res :: A * x - b = {:e}".format(res))

    # check if converged
    if np.abs(res) < tol:
        print("IR ::: A * x - b = {:e}".format(res))
        return x

    k = 1                                       # step 1
    while (k <= maxiter):                       # step 2
        r = b - A.dot(x)                        # step 3
        y = lu.solve(r)                         # step 4
        xx = copy(x + y)                        # step 5

        if k == 1:                              # step 6
            # t = 16
            # COND = np.linalg.norm(y)/np.linalg.norm(xx) * 10**t
            # print("cond is ::::", COND)
            COND = np.linalg.cond(A.toarray())

        norm_ = np.linalg.norm(x-xx) # * np.linalg.norm(x) * 1e10
        print("iteration {:3d}, norm = {:e}".format(k, norm_))

        if norm_ < tol:                         # step 7

            if verbose:
                print("Conditional number of matrix A is: {:e}".format(COND))
                print("The procedure was successful.")
                print("IR: A * x - b = {:e}".format(np.sum(A.dot(xx)-b)))
                print(f"number of iteration is : {k:d}")
                print(" ")
            return xx

        k += 1                                 # step 8
        x = copy(xx)                           # step 9

    print("Max iteration exceeded.")
    print("The procedure was not successful.")
    print("Conditional number of matrix A is: {:e}".format(COND))
    print(" ")

    return None
```

The accuracy depends on condition number and for larger ones, the accuracy disappears.

I tried some method from eigen3: [Catalogue of decompositions offered by Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html):

```
VectorXd x = A.partialPivLu().solve(b);
VectorXd x = A.fullPivLu().solve(b);
VectorXd x = A.bdcSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(b);
```

Here is the link to github for the full example in [python](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/solvers/blob/master/py/test_different_methods.ipynb) and [eigen](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/solvers/blob/master/cpp/example4_solve.cpp).
It is possible to use Eigen modules with e.g quad precision or higher? Is there any example?
I am not sure we can do this with scipy modules.

output from C++ file is:

```sh
condition number is :3.16172e+28
The relative error for                             partialPivLu  is        0.0000000000000011:
The relative error for                                fullPivLu  is        0.0157277957331164:
The relative error for                            householderQr  is        0.0000000000000020:
The relative error for                      colPivHouseholderQr  is        0.0000000000577384:
The relative error for                     fullPivHouseholderQr  is        0.0157277957331138:
The relative error for          completeOrthogonalDecomposition  is        0.0157277957331138:
The relative error for                                      llt  is                      -nan:
The relative error for                                     ldlt  is        0.0000000001045718:
The relative error for                                     ldlt  is 396613336624311706845184.0000000000000000:
The relative error for                                   bdcSvd  is        0.0157277957329992:
The relative error for                                jacobiSvd  is        0.0157277957528586:
```

I put the python and C++ code in the link attached in case.

Comment: Maybe try to change numbers to higher precision, `np.float128`? Also if you provided a bit more easily reproducible example (with expected output), maybe I could help.

Comment: I put the full code to the the link. It seems work for this matrix but I am still not sure for larger condition numbers. np.float128 does not work. `TypeError: cannot upcast [float128] to a floating point format`

Comment: You can use arbitrary scalar types in Eigen: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html (they need to support certain operations depending on the decomposition you want to do, of course). This is not necessarily the best way to solve ill-conditioned problems, though.

Comment: @Abolfazl That not necessarily means that np.float128 does not work. Maybe you need some small change in the code. You say there is accuracy problem, but how do you know what is expected value? Again, it would be **really** easier for me to help you if I could just copy paste your code and then try to fix it, while knowing what is expected function output.

Comment: Generally I don't know the accurate answer,  I don't know if  i am correct, eigen documentation suggest to check the "if a solution really exists" with `relative_error = (A*x - b).norm() / b.norm()`.  I put the full example code in the attached link to google drive. For the attached matrix it seems the accuracy if fine but I cant be sure for larger condition numbers.